# How to Grant Permissions without User Interaction?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Instead of the interactive/runtime permissions, how can I set the permissions at install OR sticky permission so that this doesnt come up everytime I run the app.

The two permissions are LOCATION & CAMERA.

Comment: You cant, permissions must be user granted otherwise it would be no different than what we had before

Comment: sorry didnt mention that this is a private application. So the first time the user grants the permission it would be good enough. Also, I have seen some apps have a check box to "remember" the permissions. How do they do it?

Comment: Android 6.0+ runtime permissions already are "sticky permission so that this doesnt come up everytime I run the app". A user might revoke permissions via Settings, but they have to proactively do that. Otherwise, once a user grants you permission, it is yours until the app is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you request permissions in your manifest file so that the user can agree when he installs the application.

However, there has been a change recently in Android 6.0 which requires that the user is asked at runtime if the permission is dangerous. The `android.permission.CAMERA` permission is on of those dangerous permissions. As noted by [mmBs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49301725/4540114) you could set your target API level to less than Android 6.0 (e.g. 21 = 5.0) to achieve backwards compatible behaviour. But I would recommend to always update the target API level to the latest platform.

Nevertheless, you can take photos by capturing the photo using an intent (https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html). That way your app doesn't need the CAMERA permission (the other app invoked by your intent does, but not yours).